# Scalable wiki software

Tags: open-source, wiki

I am looking for advice on choosing a wiki software for a project. The specific requirements are:

- Scalability (should be scalable to accommodating large number of articles > 10,000),
- extensibility,
- author restrictions on editing pages (that is, some pages can be edited by a certain group of authors while the others might be freely editable),
- language support,
- free and open source, and
- relatively easy to set up.

Comment: I suppose we have already read http://www.wikimatrix.org/ [1] http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ChoosingaWiki [2] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_wiki_software [3]

Answer (score 1):

[mediawiki have *ACL*'s](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Access_Control_List) to limit read/write access on pages based on predefined rules.

There are extensions for other functionality. There are documentations about how to write new extensions.

As of scalability, wikipedia already host gigabytes of text.

Languages may or may not be a problem. We write utf8 text. East Asian and right-to-left scripts are handled properly. [rfc 7231 section 5.3.5](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-5.3) style http content negotiation by language seems *not supported* (correct me if I'm wrong).

mediawiki depends on php and mysql. Deployment is *not* as easy as text based systems, but I guess for a big site with 10 000+ aritcles, some database is necessary anyway.

Though already widely adopted, [the syntax is criticised](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/tiddlywiki/M_nLRtXRVWY/uzW_dy12MiAJ).

Comment: Hi, thanks. Do you think mediawiki is the best for my requirements or are there others that would be more easily extensible etc?

Answer (score 0):

I won't answer your question by giving you a fish (Wiki), rather I will teach you, and anyone else who wants to choose a wiki, *how* to fish.

Visit [Wiki matrix](http://www.wikimatrix.org/) and plug in your requirements. That will give you the answer that you want (and you might find some "nice to have" features while you are at it).